# Why is there an error on the colon in ${attribute:find...?

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to use [RouteOnAttribute](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.11.4/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.RouteOnAttribute/index.html) to filter on a regex. To do so, I added two attributes in the Properties:

| Property | Value |
| --- | --- |
| private | `${ip:find('^(10|127|169\.254|172\.1[6-9]|172\.2[0-9]|172\.3[0-1]|192\.168)\.')}` |
| public | `${ip:find('^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?<!172\.(16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31))(?<!127)(?<!^10)(?<!^0)\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?<!192\.168)(?<!172\.(16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31))\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$')}` |

This processor shows two errors, both the same: `Unexpected token ':' at line 1 column 4`

Why is this an error?

Comment: Assuming there's an attribute called `ip` the error message might be a red herring. Try escaping the last `$` as `\$` to ensure it is not trying to evaluate it as Expression Language

Comment: @mattyb: thanks but it did not help (and there is no `$` in the first regex). `ip` is explicitly defined as an attribute upstream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an expression language function called [`ip`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#ip). Try quoting the "ip" (single or double should be supported) and it should parse it as a FlowFile attribute and not a function name.

Comment: That was it, thank you. I changed the attribute property to `parsedIp` and it worked fine.